# Need help to set up jquery countdown in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, web-applications, jquery-countdown

I have made a Rails app to conduct a computer adaptive test. I need to put a timer in the exam so that exam gets over as soon as time is over. I have tried and searched all over the internet but couldn't find a solution. Thanks for your help :)

P.S.- Don't get angry if you think it is a childish question.

Answer (score 3):

Use the rails session for this . In your controller you put like this :
   session[:current_user_id] = @user.id

For setting the expiration period for sessions in your application, simply add the following option to your config/intializers/session_store.rb file:

:expire_after => 60.minutes // or specified time

As soon as session ends you finish up with the test .

Answer (score 0):

First response from Google: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

You could go with something like:

```
//On the page start
var timeToEndTest = 600; //10 min

setTimeout(endTest, timeToEndTest);
```

Being `endTest`some function that will end the test